# How to find special chain charactes in a string and change color?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

My string could look like this: `Numbers: [3]` or `Numbers: [213]`

How I can find `[]` and number inside it and change color of **[]** and **number**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be divided into 2 sections

1. the colour change.
   You have to create a string class in this format

```
 var text :String = "<font color=#000>[</font><font color=#6ab04c>213</font><font color=#000>]</font>";


textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

2. Finding the values.

In the textwatcher search for the occurrence of the '[' and then format the string accordingly.
so a non optimal solution would be
str1= "["
str2="219"
str3="]"

Now construct the string as mentioned in the section and then set to the textview